# takeEvery but it is discarding every single one

Tags: redux-saga

I am trying to only process one download of a given ID at a time. I want it non-blocking, so "different file IDs" can download in parallel, that's why I am doing `takeEvery`. I want to discard if a "same file ID" is already in progress.

Once the action `DOWNLOAD_FILE` is dispatched, I set the in the reducer, `file.isDownloading = true`. However the `downloadFileWorker` is always finding it is true and discarding.

Here is my saga:

```
const DOWNLOAD_FILE = 'DOWNLOAD_FILE';
export function downloadFile(id) {
    return {
        type: DOWNLOAD_FILE,
        id
    }
}
function* downloadFileWorker(action) {
    const { id } = action;

    const state = yield select();
    const files = state;

    const file = files.find(file => file.id === id);
    if (file.isDownloading) {
        console.log('discontinuing worker as file is already downloading');
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('OK CONTINUE TO DOWNLOAD');
        const res = yield call(fetch, ...);
        const json = yield call(res.json);
        console.log('json:', json);
    }
}
function* downloadFileWatcher() { // i think i can call this downloadFileSaga
    yield takeEvery(DOWNLOAD_FILE, downloadFileWorker);
}
```

We see here this first finds the file in the state, and if its `isDownloading` then it doesn't continue (in `downloadFileWorker`).

When the `DOWNLOAD_FILE` action is triggered though, in the reducer I set the file to `isDownloading` so my worker is always discarding. This is my reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state=INITIAL, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case DOWNLOAD_FILE: {
            const { id } = action;
            const files = state;
            if (!files) return state;

            const file = files.find(file => file.id === id);
            if (!file) return state;

            if (file.isDownloading) {
                console.log('discarding reducer action, as file is already downloading');
                return state;
            }

            return files.map( file => file.id !== id ? file : { ...file, isDownloading:true } )
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when action is dispatched the reducer is always executed first and only then the saga. One way to solve this is to split the flow into two actions. One - DOWNLOAD_FILE - to start the saga and then second -
 e.g. DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED - to be dispatched from the saga when isDownloading is false and to update the isDownloading state:

```
const DOWNLOAD_FILE = 'DOWNLOAD_FILE';
const DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED = 'DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED';
export function downloadFile(id) {
    return {
        type: DOWNLOAD_FILE,
        id
    }
}
export function downloadFileStarted(id) {
    return {
        type: DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED,
        id
    }
}
function* downloadFileWorker(action) {
    const { id } = action;

    const state = yield select();
    const files = state;

    const file = files.find(file => file.id === id);
    if (file.isDownloading) {
        console.log('discontinuing worker as file is already downloading');
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('OK CONTINUE TO DOWNLOAD');
        yield put(downloadFileStarted(id));
        const res = yield call(fetch, ...);
        const json = yield call(res.json);
        console.log('json:', json);
    }
}
function* downloadFileWatcher() { // i think i can call this downloadFileSaga
    yield takeEvery(DOWNLOAD_FILE, downloadFileWorker);
}
```

...

```
export default function reducer(state=INITIAL, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED: {
            const { id } = action;
            const files = state;
            if (!files) return state;

            const file = files.find(file => file.id === id);
            if (!file) return state;

            if (file.isDownloading) {
                console.log('discarding reducer action, as file is already downloading');
                return state;
            }

            return files.map( file => file.id !== id ? file : { ...file, isDownloading:true } )
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

---

Another way to approach this, if you want avoid second action, is to remember a state between current and previous action dispatch.

```
function* downloadFileWorker(action, prevState) {
    const { id } = action;

    const files = prevState;

    const file = files.find(file => file.id === id);
    if (file.isDownloading) {
        console.log('discontinuing worker as file is already downloading');
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('OK CONTINUE TO DOWNLOAD');
        const res = yield call(fetch, ...);
        const json = yield call(res.json);
        console.log('json:', json);
    }
}
function* downloadFileWatcher() {
    while (true) {
        const prevState = yield select();
        const action = yield take(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
        yield fork(downloadFileWorker, action, prevState);
    } 
}
```

`prevState` isn't necessarily exactly the previous state, but it should be some state between last two DOWNLOAD_FILE dispatches and so the isDownloading state should have the correct value.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin for your help. I was hoping to avoid creating another action though of `DOWNLOAD_FILE_STARTED`, because I wanted to make use of the `DOWNLOAD_FILE` - because right now the action is ignored by the reducer, I wanted to put it to good use, is this not possible?

Comment: I thought of another way to do this, I updated my answer to include the other solution :)

Comment: Very cool thank you Martin! So the `watcher` always triggers before the `reducer` which triggers before the `worker`? Is this the life cycle?

Comment: Well, the watcher will usually wait only on the `yield take(DOWNLOAD_FILE)` so the select for next `prevState` will happen immediately after the fork and then it will wait again for another action. Generally it should work exactly as before with `takeEvery` except that after the `fork` it will always store the state to pass it into the next worker.

Comment: Ohhh yes!! Thank you Martin for helping with this understanding.